# how to reload the picker view with new data

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I am loading the picker view first time with the values which stored in array.

I am using,

```
temp = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Male", @"Female", nil];

- (NSString *)pickerView:addData titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
                                forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [temp objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

But it shows the empty picker view.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try `[somePickerVier reloadAllComponents];`?

Also, the correct delegate method is `- (NSString *)pickerView:` *`(UIPickerView *)pickerView`* `titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you set the delegate and datasource?

If not,

You have to implement this in your .h file

```
@interface YourView : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource>
```

Comment: i am not able to reload my picker view dynamically using reload all components..why?

Comment: how you are reloading? using your pickerView variable? If so, have you linked it to the IB?

Answer (score 0):

u have been using autorelease array
so u have to retain this if u want

u dont like this

then do alloc and init then

add male,female...

temp = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Male", @"Female", nil]retain];

- (NSString *)pickerView:addData titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
                              forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

  return [temp objectAtIndex:row];

}